# How to submit the hidden input fields also along with file in dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

I am a newbie to this dropzone.js I have a doubt that how could submit hidden input field values along with the file.
this is my code that I have tried help guide me if I am going wrong some where.

HTML and php code:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i= const; $i++){?>
<form id="upload1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" id="key" name="key" value="<?php echo $key;?>">
  <div id="dZUpload-<?php echo $i?>" class="dropzone dZUpload">
    <div class="dz-default dz-message"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right submit_files" id="<?php echo $key;?>">Submit this form!</button>
  </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
<input type="hidden" id="testkey" value=""/>
```

and this is my javacript code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= $('.dropzone').length; i++) {
$("#dZUpload-"+i).dropzone({
  url: "<?php echo site_url('uploadfiles.html');?>",
  paramName: "file",
  maxFilesize: 2,
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 100,
  maxFiles: 100,
  init: function() {          
     var myDropzone = this; // closure 
     $(".submit_files").off().on("click", function(e) {
             var key = $(this).attr('id');
             e.preventDefault();
             e.stopPropagation();
             myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {                      
               formData.append("key_campiagn", key); 
             });
             myDropzone.processQueue(); 
           });    
          },
  success: function (file, response) {
    var imgName = response;
    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
  },
  addfiles: function (file) {
    alert(file);
  },
  error: function (file, response) {
    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-error");
  }
});
}
}
```

I want the submit the btn_id value along with the file. I stuck up how to   submit these values together to the specified url. Can anyone help me out with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add extra values in your `init`  function before uploading some thing like this

```
init: function() {
    this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
       var value = $('form#upload1 #key').val();
       formData.append("key", value); // Append all the additional input data of your form here!
    });
}
```

Comment: yes but on submit click  i am trying to get the key value and I have multiple dropzones in my form .So each i have different key value i need to submit this key on the submit button click.

Comment: and then you cvan specify your form too

Comment: you mean i should add it in the $(".submit_files").off().on("click", function (e) {});

Comment: whenever you want to upload the files. you can find and send them accrordingly.

Comment: Yes your correct its submit .but only  the last one can you code at the code above i haved changed it and provide me the solution for it

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation :

> Dropzone will submit any hidden fields you have in your dropzone form.
>   So this is an easy way to submit additional data. You can also use the
>   params option.

source : http://www.dropzonejs.com/#tips

So it is possible to do it like this :

```
<form action="/" method="post" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">

     <input type="hidden" value="xxx" name="nom_prenom">

     <input type="hidden" value="yyy" name="product_name">

</form>
```

and in your PHP file :

```
$nom_prenom = $_POST["nom_prenom"];
$product_name = $_POST["product_name"];
```

Comment: According to documentation...but this does not work...for me. My hidden input are inside a form, but if I don't add them manually with formData.append they will not fetch from server side